# Timepicker popup not closing after selecting the date

Tags: jquery, popup, timepicker

I have used timepicker addon from [http://trentrichardson.com](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Here I have one problem, Timepicker popup is not closing after I selecting the date.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker" runat="server" CssClass="datetimepicker" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
});
```

Right now it shows just like this:

[image: Date]

So on selecting the date, I want it to close.

Comment: It is not supposed to close, because you wouldn't be able to select hour & minutes. Or have I misunderstood your intent? How would you like it to behave?

Comment: @Xeon I just updated my question..

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this plugin prevents adding neat jQuery code for hiding.

It would be something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-datepicker a", function() {
    $(this).closest(".ui-datepicker").hide();
});
```

But it `prevevents propagation` of click event and invoking other click handlers, so above doesn't work.

The below solution is in a bad style, but it works (http://jsfiddle.net/cL9Fx/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
    $("#datetimepicker").click(function() {
        $(".ui-datepicker a").each(function(index, elem) {
            $(elem).attr("onclick", "$(this).closest(\".ui-datepicker\").fadeOut(\"fast\");");
        });
    });
});
```